# How to access class object when I use torch.nn.DataParallel()?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, multi-gpu

I want to train my model using PyTorch with multiple GPUs. I included the following line:

```
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=opt.gpu_ids)
```

Then, I tried to access the optimizer that was defined in my model definition:

```
G_opt = model.module.optimizer_G
```

However, I got an error:

> AttributeError: 'DataParallel' object has no attribute optimizer_G

I think it is related with the definition of optimizer in my model definition. It works when I use single GPU without `torch.nn.DataParallel`. But it does not work with multi GPUs even though I call with `module` and I could not find the solution.

Here is the model definition:

```
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    ...
   self.optimizer_G = torch.optim.Adam(params, lr=opt.lr, betas=(opt.beta1, 0.999))
```

I used Pix2PixHD implementation in [GitHub](https://github.com/NVIDIA/pix2pixHD) if you want to see the full code.

Thank you,
Best.

Edit: I solved the problem by using `model.module.module.optimizer_G`.

Comment: The original code has "model.module" although there is no torch.nn.DataParallel() code. So, when I use model.module.module, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use **model.module** , but sometime before running the model it doesn't work for some reason, use **model.module.module** at that time.

Best of luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).